# Click function on the table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, twitter-bootstrap, click

I'd like  to make a function on click on tabes first cell in each row only. This is table built with plugin and this method does not work

```
$('#ecoTableTotal').find('tr').find('td').eq(0).click(function(){
    console.log('click');
})
```

This one is working, but I need this to click only on the first cell. Is this possible?

```
 $('#ecoTableTotal').on('click', 'tr' , function (event) {
        console.log('click');
    });
```

EDIT:
Table is generated using Bootstrap table (http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567867/bootstrap-table-cannot-add-click-event-on-tr) is also about the same problem with click function.

Comment: There can be an if and else check while you are generating the TD...are you okay with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:first-of-type` selector: http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rejaye/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

As suggested elsewhere, `:first-child` **will not work**

- it will not target the `i` element (as per your request) that are really the first `i` to appear. i.e: if before an `i` element you have a `<br>` or `<b>bold</b>` than `i:first-child` is **not any more the first-child**!

---

Seems from your comments that your TR are created dynamically, so do like

```
$('#ecoTableTotal').on("click", "tr td:first-of-type i:first-of-type", function(){
   console.log('click');
});
```

More info about how to use: [use `.on()` with event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

---

To resume, you can use this two variants:

```
"tr td:first-of-type i:first-of-type"
```

or

```
"tr td:first-child i:first-of-type"
// TD is always the first inside a valid TABLE TR so only here we can use 
// first-child, but there's no guarantee that a contextual <i> element is not 
// preceded by some other HTML element tag.
```

Comment: @Anuket jsBin has his own `Console`, click on the button to open it.

Comment: @Anuket simply move to the right (into the second function argument) all the selectors you add to the page dynamically to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Selector > means that you are interested only in direct child element, it helps to define deph of your selector.

```
$('#ecoTableTotal').on('click', 'tbody > tr > td:first' , function (event) {
        console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: `tbody` is optional and mostly added by the Browser.

Comment: I was told that it is a good thing to always use it, that all tables should have it. Either way I try to define it in all my tables.

Comment: when someone tolds you something, be the first to prove he's wrong ;) http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element

Comment: So now I need to check if your data is correct:) tanks for info, will remember it:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ecoTableTotal').on('click', 'tr td:first-child' , function (event) {
    console.log('click');
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$('#ecoTableTotal').on('click', 'tr td:eq(0)' , function (event) {
    console.log('click');
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$('#ecoTableTotal').on('click', 'tr td:eq(0) i:eq(0)' , function (event) {
    console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, only this one work. Could it be extended to click only on <i> element (the only element) in this cell?

Comment: @Anuket, kindly check my post

Comment: @Arvind in your example, using `('#ecoTableTotal').on('click', 'tr i:first-child' , function (event) {` will not target any more only the first `i` *`(c.)"inside this cell"`*, but also the *first `i`* inside every other cell.